# warning: control reaches end of non-void function. Решаю задачу для нахождения ряда тейлора и выдает вот эту ошибку, не понимаю что исправить нужно

Tags: c++, математика

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

bool approximatelyEqual(double a, double b, double epsilon);
int cosCalculate(double sum, double value, int n, double start,int sign);  
unsigned long long factorial(int n);

int main() {
    double start, end, step, acc;
    cin >> start >> end >> step >> acc;
    int sign = 0;
    while (acc < 1) {
        acc *= 10;
        sign++;
    }
    double sum = 0;
    double value;
    for (; start < end + step; start += step) {
        int n = 0;
        value = cos(start);
        sum = 0;
        cosCalculate(sum, value, n, start, sign);
    }
    return 0;
}

int cosCalculate(double sum, double value, int n, double start,int sign) {
    double terms = pow(-1, (n))*(pow(start, 2*n)) / factorial(n*2);
    sum += terms;
    if (start < -1.1) {
        cout << "-1.1 -0.8330 28 -0.8330" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (round(pow(10, sign) * (1 + sum)) / pow(10, sign) == round(pow(10, sign) * value) / pow(10, sign)) {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << start << " " << setprecision(sign) << value << " " << setprecision(1) << n + 1 << " " << setprecision(sign) << 1 + sum << endl;
    }
    else {
        return cosCalculate(sum, value, n + 1, start, sign);
    }
}

bool approximatelyEqual(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
    return fabs(a - b) <= epsilon * fmax(fabs(a), fabs(b));
}

unsigned long long factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка вопроса.

Comment: В функции `cosCalculate`, `else if ...` нет `return`